# agregar una cadena de String en codigo android

Tags: android-studio

quisiera saber como puedo agregar un texto que se encuentra en mi archivo strings en un arreglo como este para no tener problemas cuando cambie de idioma en el dispositivo :

```
public String[] list_title={
         "paso 1",
        "paso 2",
        "paso 3",
        "paso 4",
        "paso 5"
};
```

no se si me entienda o tenga solución al correrlo si concateno directo (""+R.String.xxx) me manda la dirección del string mas no el texto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para coger el contenido del fichero strings debes usar el getResources y cuando cambies de idioma solo tendrás que replicar el fichero strings.xml.

```
getResources().getString(R.string.tuTexto)
```

Comment: calificala como respondida si resolvio tu duda.

Comment: al principio todo estaba bien pero  me pide que aplique un Context.getResources().getString(R.string.tuTexto)
 y despues al correrlo mi app crashea

Comment: Te aconsejo que googlees el error a ver si logras solucionarlo y en caso que no puedes poner otra pregunta a ver si alguien encuentra la solución pero no olvides poner el stacktrace del error

Comment: lo  hare vere que puedo encontrar gracias.